# Wordpress tax_query "and" operator not functioning as desired

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, tax-query

I have a custom post type of **image** with a custom taxonomy called **image_tag** (it's hierarchical like categories). Here are some examples of the tags that might be used:

```
Structure (id: 25)
- House (id: 56)
- Skyscraper
Nature
- Animal
- Plant (id: 41)
```

So, I want to drill down through the images by selecting multiple tags in conjunction with the "and" operator. For example, finding all photos with **plant**s and **house**s.

```
$query_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'image',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'image_tag',
      'terms' => array(41, 56),    // IDs of "plant" and "house"
      'operator' => 'and',
    ),
  ),
);
```

That works fine, the problem begins when I try to include the parent terms, for example:

```
$query_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'image',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'image_tag',
      'terms' => array(25, 41),    // IDs of "structure" and "plant"
      'operator' => 'and',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Then I get no results. I'm guessing that because I'm using the "and" operator, Wordpress doesn't include the children of the "Structure" term. Does anyone have an idea how I can get this to work, or some other solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

not tested but give this a shot

```
'tax_query' => array(
   'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'image_tag',
      'field'    => 'term_id',
      'terms'    => 25,
      'operator' => 'IN',
    ),
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'image_tag',
      'field'    => 'term_id',
      'terms'    => 41,
      'operator' => 'IN',
    )
  ),
```

OR

```
'tax_query' => array(
   'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'image_tag',
      'field'    => 'term_id',
      'terms'    => array(25,41),
      'operator' => 'IN',
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Thanks for your time!  For anyone else who may find this, the first solution is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to comment yet, but on the accepted answer, a slight modification of the second solution is `'operator' => 'AND'`, and the `relation` variable can be done away with. Seems that the `operator` variable specifies the relation of the terms within its array, while the `relation` variable specifies the relation for groups of terms
[Source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters)